# How to get the picklist value not id in to controller

Tags: visualforce, apex

In my requirement I am filling one picklist value by querying from different object based on some condition and filling it,

```
<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!SelectedValue}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!Autofill}" reRender="af"/>
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!stockproducts}"/>

public List<SelectOption> getstockproducts() {
          List<SelectOption> mystock = new List<SelectOption>();
          for(CarBoot_Stock__c getst : [SELECT id,SKU_name__c FROM CarBoot_Stock__c where Total_Cases_in_Boot__c>0 and User_Boot__c=:userinfo.getuserid()]) {
              mystock.add(new SelectOption(getst.Id, getst.SKU_name__c));
              System.debug('mystock--------'+mystock);
              //System.debug('mystock--------'+mystock.label);
          }
          return mystock;      }
```

after showing it in VF page when I am going to save the record with selected value I am getting the Id(SelectedValue) of the picklist not actual value.

Can anyone please guide me to get the actual value ,so that I have to assign it to some value to save the record.

Comment: Does the select options have to be keyed to ID? `mystock.add(new SelectOption(getst.Id, getst.SKU_name__c));`

Answer (score 0):

Does the select options have to be keyed to ID? `mystock.add(new SelectOption(getst.Id, getst.SKU_name__c));` if not just do  `mystock.add(new SelectOption(getst.SKU_name__c, getst.SKU_name__c));`